# Using a module.export function inside the same file same file where it's implemented

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a controller with two functions:

```js
module.exports.getQuestionnaire = function(application, req, res) {
}

module.exports.getClientDetails = function(application, req, res) {
}
```

I want to call the `getQuestionnaire` function inside the `getClientDetails` function.

Just calling `getQuestionnaire()` does not work. How should I do this?

Comment: Call it like `exports.getQuestionnaire()` or `module.exports.getQuestionnaire()`

Comment: How can I pass an argument, like client id?

Comment: What do you mean? Pass it just like you do in normal functions `exports.getQuestionnaire(clientId)`

Comment: If I do module.exports.getDadosQuestionarioET(clientid, application, req, res ) inside getClientDetails, which have clientid defined, it throws an error: ReferenceError: clientid is not defined. I have also changed the module.exports.getDadosQuestionarioET = function(clientid, application, req, res) {

Comment: I was doing wrong, it passed. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I usually do:

```js
const getQuestionnaire = () => {
  //getClientDetails()
}
    
const getClientDetails = () => {
  //getQuestionnaire()
}
    
module.exports = {getQuestionnaire, getClientDetails}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define each one as a separate function and then export the functions. Then you can also use the functions on the page

```
function getQuestionnaire(application, req, res) { }
function getClientDetails (application, req, res) { }
module.exports = {getQuestionnaire, getClientDetails}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
function getQuestionnaire(application, req, res) { 
 //function body
}

function getClientDetails(application, req, res) { 
  getQestionnaire(app,req,res)
}

module.exports= {getQestionnaire,getClientDetails}
```

Comment: `module.exports= {getQestionnaire}` In this case `getClientDetails` wont export anymore